# If $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition then f is bounded variation in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

If $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition then $f$ is bounded variation in $\mathbb{R}$? A function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition at if $\exists M>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $|f(x)−f(y)|≤M|x−y|$

My answer is no, I try to find a example.I know that Dirichlet function is not of bounded variation on any interval in $\mathbb{R}$, but
$f(x)=1$ if $x \in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x)=0$ if $f \in \mathbb{R- Q}$ satifies Lipschitz condition?

Do you have another example?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, your Dirichlet function does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition. You can pick a ration point $q$ and an irrational $p$ with distance $\epsilon$ but $|f(q)-f(p)|\equiv 1$. Notice that the Lipschitz condition implies that the function has bounded derivative (if it exists).

Comment: @Aaron a function satisfying the Lipschitz condition  is continuous...

Comment: In your definition of Lipschitz conditions, You should say $\exists M\ge 0 : \forall (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2...$

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(x)=x \;\; for \;\; x\in \Bbb R$$

then

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|\le \color{red}{1}|x-y|$$

$ f $ is Lipschitz and unbounded.

Comment: the OP asked about the bounded variation and not about the boundness of a function. $f\in Lip(\Omega)$ indeed implies $f\in BV(\Omega)$